# Disable comments auto-formatting in Netbeans PHP?

Tags: netbeans, ide, editor, netbeans-8

In other Netbeans version (e.g., Java), Comments category is available in this menu:

[image]

Disabling comments formatting can be done in this menu in Netbeans Java but not in Netbeans PHP.

I believe it's been several versions already but this functionality is still missing in the Netbeans PHP version.

Is there a way to manually disable comments formatting somewhere in the Netbeans config file? Note: This is Netbeans `8.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution for this in the short term.

I'm not sure if it is exactly what you want, but there is a planned fix for [NetBeans Bug 230814](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230814) "Auto creation of * in comments should only apply to /** blocks and not to /* blocks":

> Netbeans doesn't currently allow you to do simple multiline comments
>   in php without breaking the formatting. Multi line comments should be
>   a trivial feature of any simple text editor or basic IDE, let alone a
>   mature one like Netbeans.

Unfortunately the fix will not be applied until "[after NetBeans 9.0 is released](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230814#c18)", which should be happening within the next few weeks.

You can [download a beta release of NetBeans 9.0 as a zip file](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90-beta.html), but that probably won't help you unless they decided to include the fix as part of the 9.0 release after all.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know if there's a Netbeans 9 for PHP beta version? The link appears to be for Netbeans for Java. Couldn't find info anywhere for Netbeans 9 for PHP.

Comment: @IMB Download and unzip NetBeans 9, and start NetBeans. Then **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins > PHP > Install**. That plugin _"Provides tools and support for PHP development. Includes PHP editor, debugger, samples and documentation"_. There are several other PHP plugins that you might also want to install (PHPUnit, PHP Static Analysis, etc.).